# What is the difference between pluck and collect in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Here are two sample codes.

First one with `collect`:

```
User.first.gifts.collect(&:id)
```

Second one with `pluck`:

```
User.first.gifts.pluck(:id)
```

Is there any difference between them in performance or something else?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

`pluck` is on the db level. It will only query the particular field. [See this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck).

When you do:

```
 User.first.gifts.collect(&:id)
```

You have objects with all fields loaded and you simply get the `id` thanks to the method based on Enumerable.

So:

- if you **only** need the `id` with Rails 4, use `ids`: `User.first.gifts.ids`
- if you **only** need some fields with Rails 4, use `pluck`: `User.first.gifts.pluck(:id, :name, ...)`
- if you **only** need one field with Rails 3, use `pluck`: `User.first.gifts.pluck(:id)`
- if you need **all** fields, use `collect`
- if you need some fields with Rails 4, still use `pluck`
- if you need some fields with Rails 3, use `select`and `collect`

Comment: "if you need some fields, use selectand collect" - can't you just use `pluck` with multiple attributes, like `pluck(:id, :name)`?

Comment: @AlexPopov - Rails 4+ supports ```pluck```ing multiple fields, Rails 3 does not, unless you use [Ryan Lefevre's workaround](http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/)

Comment: In Rails 4, if you *only* need the `id`, use `.ids` Ref doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-ids

Answer (score 37):

Yes. [According to Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck), `pluck` directly converts a database result into an `array`, without constructing `ActiveRecord` objects. This means better performance for a large or often-running query.

In addition to @apneadiving's answer, `pluck` can take both single and multiple column names as argument:

```
Client.pluck(:id, :name)
# SELECT clients.id, clients.name FROM clients
# => [[1, 'David'], [2, 'Jeremy'], [3, 'Jose']]
```

Answer (score 4):

The basic and main difference is that Pluck applies on db level and collect get all data and then return record to you
when you need all records use collect and when few fields then use pluck

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but if you would like a deeper `pluck` you can use `includes`:

```rb
User.all.includes(:groups).pluck("users.id", "users.name", "groups.id", "groups.name")
```

This results in a bigger array like

```rb
[
  [12, "Sam", 4, "FriendsRUs"],
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is a case where you are using few attributes of the retrieved record. In such cases you should use `pluck` .

```
User.collect(&:email)
```

In above example if you only need email attribute than you are wasting memory and time. Because it will retrieve all the columns from user table in the database, allocates the memory for each attributes (including the attributes which you will never use)

NOTE: `pluck` does not return ActiveRecord_Relation of the user

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `collect` and `pluck` is that `collect` loads all the attributes from DB while `pluck` loads only the attributes you have mentioned.
For example, when you do:

```
User.all.collect(&:id)
```

this loads all the attributes of User records in memory and returns the ids.
And when you do:

```
User.all.pluck(:id)
```

this loads only the ids in memory so it is more efficient in case you need to access only few attributes.