# Simple active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a feeling this question is easy, but maybe I am just overthinking it..

I have an Active Record query that looks like this:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.includes(:owner, :trackable).where(owner_id: current_user.followed_users, owner_type: "User", kind: "Activity")
```

This works great, but I'd like to add `current_user` as a possible `:owner`. So I've tried many options, including:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.includes(:owner, :trackable).where(owner_id: [[current_user.followed_users], [current_user]], owner_type: "User", kind: "Activity")
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.includes(:owner, :trackable).where(owner_id: [current_user.followed_users, current_user], owner_type: "User", kind: "Activity")
```

However I'm getting errors like:

```
Cannot visit User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
```

Can anyone spot the mistake I'm making...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_user.followed_users` is an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, but you only want the ids, like so - `current_user.followed_users.collect(&:id)`

Using your example, the full query would look something like this:

`@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.includes(:owner, :trackable).where(owner_id: [[current_user.followed_users.collect(&:id)], [current_user.id]], owner_type: "User", kind: "Activity")`

Comment: use #pluck instead of collect to only grab the ids

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176102/what-is-the-difference-between-pluck-and-collect-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

You can append the current_user to the array of followed_users. Try this:

```
allowed_users = current_user.followed_users << current_user
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.includes(:owner, :trackable).where(owner_id: allowed_users, owner_type: "User", kind: "Activity")
```

Or you can just add `current_user` as a one element array to the their `followed_users`.

```
allowed_users = current_user.followed_users + [current_user]
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.includes(:owner, :trackable).where(owner_id: allowed_users, owner_type: "User", kind: "Activity")
```

Comment: thanks this does work as well. If brad doesn't edit his current answer, then I will accept this.