# How do i parse an activerecord query to produce collection?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My view code is as below:

```
<%= b.input :city, as: :select, collection: Lov.where(:remarks => 'lov_city').select('id').select('lov_content'),  placeholder: 'Enter City', label: false %>
```

When the code is render, the list of data that is shown in my view is `#<Lov:0x3241351>` ..

Actually the Lov table is a reference table which is not related to any other tables and when i do in the rails console (rails c)  and running the same '`Lov.where(:remarks => 'lov_city').select('id').select('lov_content')`' the data is shown but the view is different.

From rails console:

```
jruby-1.7.16.1 :001 > Lov.where(:remarks => 'lov_city').select('id').select('lov_content')
  lovs Columns (6.0ms)  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `lovs`
  Lov Load (8.0ms)  SELECT id, lov_content FROM `lovs` WHERE `lovs`.`remarks` = 'lov_city'
 => [#<Lov id: 229, lov_content: "Ayer Baloi">, #<Lov id: 230, lov_content: "Ayer Hitam">, #<Lov id: 231, lov_content: "Ayer Tawar 2">, #<Lov id: 232, lov_content: "Ayer Tawar 3">, #<Lov id: 233, lov_content: "Ayer Tawar 4">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch some selected column then use [`pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck)

```
Lov.where(:remarks => 'lov_city').pluck(:id, :lov_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Lov.where(:remarks => 'lov_city').select('id').select('lov_content')
```

This will return an active record object with only an id and lov_content as attribute. I am not sure of what you are trying to display but you need to provide a collection of value instead of an activerecord object.

First of all you can select several attributes at once without having to write several time select such as:

```
Lov.where(:remarks => 'lov_city').select([:id, :lov_content])
```

if you need to provide the list of lov_content then you can use this to return an array of lov_content:

```
Lov.where(:remarks => 'lov_city').collect(&:lov_content)
```

Comment: I had missing attribute :id once so i had selected the id. (in fact i only selected 'lov_content' only at first). I wanted to provide the list of lov_content based on the remarks (for example, it has lov_gender, lov_state, lov_marital in remarks column like lov_city - all of the items are for reference).

.collect is what i needed and again thanks!

Comment: Better use `pluck` instead of `collect` here, see the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176102/what-is-the-difference-between-pluck-and-collect-in-rails