# Pluck in a selected object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
User.find([1,2,3])
```

I want to get `name` only in User model. I don't want to loop in an object so I tried:

```
User.find([1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
```

But no luck. How can I do the following scenario using `pluck` behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pluck` will not work in that case. So instead of using `pluck`:

```
User.find([1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
```

Try using `map`:

```
User.find([1,2,3]).map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 8):

`pluck` works on `ActiveRecord::Relation`. `find` returns you objects.

I assume, you want to use `pluck` for the reason that it would make a single SQL query and get `name`s alone rather than fetching all of them records and looping over them like `map` does to get the `name`

In that case, you would want to use `where` like

```
User.where(id: [1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
```

`where` chained with `pluck` would be the optimal way for your use case.

Documentation: [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), [where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) and [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Answer (score 7):

The `find` method return an array and `pluck` is not an array method:

```
2.1.1 :001 > User.find([1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
  User Load (3.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3)
NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x0000000f22ed90>
```

So if you want to do it using `find` you may do it like this:

```
User.find([1,2,3]).collect(&:name)
```

Or

You can do it like this:

```
User.where(id: [1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
```

And if you need the difference between `pluck` and `collect` you may refer this:

[What is the difference between pluck and collect in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176102/what-is-the-difference-between-pluck-and-collect-in-rails)

**Update for Rails 5**

In rails 5 this will work:

```
User.find([1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
```

as [Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057388/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) mentioned that the `pluck` method is now added to `Enumerable` objects.

Comment: In Rails 5 `pluck` [is an enumerable method](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20350), so it can be called on the Array.

Comment: Thanks @Зелёный for the update. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In `rails 5` it should work fine. But it wont work for any older versions.

But I think using `where` is more suitable,

```
User.where(id: [1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
```

Because `find` raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error if one or more records with `id: [1,2,3]` not found.