# How to Write Efficient Active Record Queries

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am relatively new to ActiveRecord, which I use alongside Sinatra. Currently, I am building small scale websites. I have not run into any issues with queries taking too long, but I want to know how to optimize searches best, so my site is scalable.

This is something I have been wondering for awhile. Does ActiveRecord treat a query that is broken down into multiple functions different from one that is just one function?

```
# Single
BlogPost.last(5)

# Broken Down
BlogPost.all.limit(5)
```

This is more of a conceptual question: how does ActiveRecord run searches? Do more functions added make searches less efficient? When you have a query that is broken down into multiple functions `BlogPost.where(publish: true)` - let's say the `where(publish: true)` returns fifty results and the `limit` limits it to five. Does it first find all fifty `publish: true` and then cut off everything after five, or is it smart enough to stop the search after it finds the first five?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunches are correct. It's a good practice to chain ActiveRecord queries.

Say your BlogPost table has a million rows.

To then say `BlogPost.all` would be slow, but to say `BlogPost.all.limit(1)` would be fast.

[all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/all/class) and [limit](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) are both part of ActiveRecord. The return values respond to Array methods but are not arrays. There are some exceptions to this. [find_by / find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161663/find-vs-find-by-vs-where) return model instances, for example, but you can put them as the last query method in a chain. [pluck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176102/what-is-the-difference-between-pluck-and-collect-in-rails) return a plain ruby array.

`BlogPost.all[1]` would be just as slow as `BlogPost.all`, because [[ ]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D) is an array method, not ActiveRecord.

When you chain together ActiveRecord methods, the query or queries are not executed until you convert the method to a array or attempt to read some of the data.

So `query = BlogPost.all.order(id: :desc).reorder(id: :asc).limit(1)` has not actually loaded any data from the database. Also read into [preloading data](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/))which can address slow [N+1](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) queries.

If you then said `query.to_a`, `query.reduce`, etc., then [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) (what ActiveRecord is built on), finalizes the query and executes it.

You can call `<query>.to_sql` to see the underlying query:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Foo.all.to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"foos\".* FROM \"foos\""
Foo.all.limit(1).to_sql
#=> "SELECT  \"foos\".* FROM \"foos\" LIMIT 1"
```