# Ruby on Rails: What does .pluck(*some_hash.values) do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've stumbled across this snippet of code:

```
users = User.where([...])

users.group!(:character_id, :age)

user_zip = {
  character_id: :character_id,         (=> has one character)
  age:          :age,
  amount:       Arel.sql('SUM(amount)')
}

user_cleaned = users.pluck(*user_zip.values)
```

The output then is an array with the "transformed"(?) user data.

What exactly is happening here? I've never seen this before. and is it possible to use this for a single record?

Comment: What SQL server do you use? Is there any grouping in `User.where([...])`?

Comment: Postgres and yes there is grouping afterwards. forgot to add it, sorry. will edit it now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between pluck and collect in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176102/what-is-the-difference-between-pluck-and-collect-in-rails)

Comment: But it's not being called on a single record. It's being called on the relation returned by `users = User.where([...])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several noteworthy things happening in this snippet:

- Array destructuring using `*`
- `pluck`
- `Arel.sql`
- Single record

**Destructuring (*)**

Pluck is defined as

`pluck(*column_names)`

which means it takes a variable amount of arguments.

If you'd call it with

`pluck([:age, :name])`

the method would see it as an array of arrays (`[[:age, :name]]`)
so you have to "destructure" the array firs:

`pluck(*[:age, :name])`

or call it with single values in the first place:

`pluck(:age, :name)`

(which might not be possible if you receive the values as array, as in your case)

[See this Thoughtbot post for more details](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-splat-operator)

**pluck**

`pluck` does two things:

- it modifies the `select`clause of the generated SQL statement
- and it bypasses creation of the ActiveRecord Model and returns the data only.

So the following lines return the same data

```
User.all.map { |user| [user.age, user.name] }
User.all.select(:age, :name).map { |user| [user.age, user.name] }
User.pluck(:age, :name)
```

The first is the least efficient: it selects ALL columns and creates the models just to discard them when calling `map`

The second is a bit more efficient in that it only selects the required columns. Still creates the models though.

`pluck` is without the overhead of selecting *all* columns and creating the models. So it usually is faster and more memory efficient.

On the SQL level it boils down to the difference between

`select * from users`

and

`select age, name from users`

So IMHO `pluck` is especially useful for APIs or when exporting to CSVs and similar.

**Arel.sql**

Rails wants you to wrap unsafe SQL in `Arel.sql`. It is a security measure (that i personally find annoying and useless) and lets you know that you have a potentially unsafe operation that Arel/ActiveRecord can not check for you.

**Single record**

You can not call it on a single record (and it would also not make much sense, since the single record is already the result of a DB query that was executed and there a Model which has been constructed).

If you want something similar for a single record that you have already loaded from the DB:

user.attributes.values_at('age', 'name')

or you can limit the query to just return results for one record

`User.where(id: 123).pluck(:age, :name) # only one record since PK`

or
`User.where(some conditions).limit(1).pluck(:age, :name)`

Note that `pluck` is somewhat inconsistent in its return values:

If you only pluck one attribute, then it returns an array of values

`User.pluck(:name)` => ["Carl", "Mike"]

but when you pluck multiple attributes it returns an array of arrays of values

`User.pluck(:name, :age) => [["Carl", 21], ["Mike", 35]]`

Comment: Ironically though half the time when I encounter pluck its used in way that makes the code less efficient - for doing `pluck(:id)` when its not actually needed and where it prevents AR from using a subquery.

Comment: yeah,one  should not do something like this

`User.where(category_id: Category.where(....).pluck(:id))`

I most often use it for exports, reports, APIs or when providing limited amount of data for a chart or similar.

Comment: If you're actually doing any work with the results use `select_all` instead. IMHO pluck is only actually useful when you want an ordered list of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down starting at the end:

`user_zip.values` is saying "take the [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Hash.html) `user_zip` and [return an array of the values](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) from every key." For example, this hash:

```rb
user_zip = {
  character_id: :character_id,
  age:          :age,
  amount:       Arel.sql('SUM(amount)')
}
```

Would return:

```rb
[
  :character_id,
  :age,
  Arel.sql('SUM(amount)')
]
```

Moving one step up, `user_cleaned = users.pluck(*user_zip.values)` is using the [splat operator](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-splat-operator) to destructure the above array into arguments that get passed into [`pluck()`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) so that you are actually running:

```rb
users.pluck(
  :character_id,
  :age,
  Arel.sql('SUM(amount)')
)
```

As for your question about using this for a single record, the purpose of `pluck` is to retrieve values from multiple records. If you wish to retrieve only a single record then you don't use `pluck` (and it isn't a method for a single record). However you can limit your `where()` query so that it returns a single record, for example with `.limit(1)`, and then you can use `pluck` on it as described:

```rb
users = User.limit(1).where([...])
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is a very overcomplicated way of doing:

```
user_cleaned = users.group(:character_id, :age).pluck(
  :character_id,
  :age,
  Arel.sql('SUM(amount)')
)
```

Composing the hash and extracting the values from it is clever but completely pointless - it doesn't make the code more readible or maintainable.

> What exactly is happening here?

`pluck` selects the list of columns and immediately fires a database query. The result from the query is an array of arrays instead of model instances.

You would get something like:

```
[[1, 25, 100], [5, 61, 2000], [5, 16, 50]]
```

This is a handy low level tool for very simple cases. But its also wildly overused.

Half of the time its not actually needed in the first place - like almost every time someone does `pluck(:id)`.

`select_all` does the same thing - returns raw query values but it returns the resulting rows as a hash instead which is far less messy to work with.

> is it possible to use this for a single record?

Yes - if you apply a `limit(1)` or `where(id: x)`. But that is kind of silly. The overhead for creating a single model instance is negible.

Comment: whether it is pointless to construct the hash depends on how/if it is used in other places

Comment: @Pascal maybe I'm making a bit too many assumptions but I'm really just going off the code in the question. There it doesn't actually do anything meaningful and if I was to take a guess its not used at all or used to zip the results into hashes again - which is a bad use of `pluck`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start from the end. Since `pluck` is executed on database level as `SELECT pluck_columns FROM ...` it cannot be executed on single record and it cannot be executed on Array of records. It has to be called on 'ActiveRecord::Relation'.

If you run this in development environment console you will see that it creates a query like:

```
 SELECT character_id, age, SUM(amount) FROM users GROUP BY character_id, age;
```

So the "transformed" data are amounts held by groups of users of the same character_id and age.

If you need explanation of the ruby part of code like `*user_zip.values` please refer to the other answer by @anothermh

Comment: As of rails 5 `pluck` is an `Enumerable` method, as well as an `ActiveRecord::Calculations` method, so it can be called on an `Array` (or any other object that includes Enumerable), although this is an awkward implementation unless the `Array` is comprised of `Hash` objects (or another object that logically responds to `#[]`). For instance: `a = [{name: 'engineersmnky'}]` then `a.pluck(:name) #=> ["engineersmnky"]` however `a = ['engineersmnky']` could also to be called like `a.pluck(/.*(?=m)/,/m.*/) #=> [["engineers","mnky"]]`

Comment: I know about `pluck` implementation for Array and other Enumerables however it is very different from `pluck` on ActiveRecord Relation and since this case used Arel as an attribute it was obvious it wouldn't work on anything but Relation. Anyway I should have been more specific.